# Jquery conflict with css Grunt build

Tags: gruntjs

I have a issue in my grunt file, while doing grunt build i got main.css file but with **jQuery** inside the top of the css file.
please help

I tried debugging the code to check where is the issue so i got the issue is from **jQuery** file which is in the libs folder.

```
// Generated on 2013-02-27 using generator-webapp 0.1.5
'use strict';
var lrSnippet = require('grunt-contrib-livereload/lib                
/utils').livereloadSnippet;

var mountFolder = function (connect, dir) {
return connect.static(require('path').resolve(dir));
};

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {
// load all grunt tasks
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

// configurable paths
var yeomanConfig = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

var barstaskdef = {
            files: {
                "app/scripts/compiled-templates.js": [
                "app/bundles/**/templates/*.bars"
            ]
        },
        options: {
                namespace: 'JST',
                processName: function(filename) {
                    return filename
                    .replace(/^app\//, '')
                    .replace(/\.bars$/, '')
                    .replace('bundles/', '')
                    .replace('app/', '') // TODO: just make a regex once
moving is complete
                    .replace('common/', '') // see above todo
                    .replace('templates/', '');
                },
                amd: true
            }
        };

grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: yeomanConfig,

    handlebars: {
      compile: barstaskdef
    },

    replace: {
        compile: {
            src: ['dist/index.html'],
            overwrite: true,                 // overwrite matched source 
files
            replacements: [{ 
                from: "window.isOptimized = false;",
                to: "window.isOptimized = true;"
            }]
        }
    },

    watch: {
        handlebars: {
            files: [
                "app/bundles/**/templates/*.bars"
            ],
            tasks: ['handlebars', 'livereload']
        },
        livereload: {
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/img/UI_icons/{,*/}*. 
{png,jpg,jpeg,webp}'
            ],
            tasks: ['livereload']
        }
    },
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: '0.0.0.0'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        lrSnippet,
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, 'app')
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                        mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        mountFolder(connect, 'dist')
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    },
    open: {
        server: {
            path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port %>'
        }
    },
    clean: {
        dist: ['.tmp', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*'],
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://localhost:<%= connect.options.port 
%>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },
    // not used since Uglify task does concat,
    // but still available if needed
    /*concat: {
        dist: {}
    },*/
    requirejs: {
        dist: {
            // Options: https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build
/example.build.js
            options: {
                // `name` and `out` is set by grunt-usemin
                baseUrl: 'app/scripts',
                optimize: 'none',
                mainConfigFile: 'app/scripts/main.js',
                // TODO: Figure out how to make sourcemaps work with 
grunt-usemin
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/30
                //generateSourceMaps: true,
                // required to support SourceMaps
                // http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#sourcemapcomments
                preserveLicenseComments: false,
                useStrict: true,
                wrap: true,
                //uglify2: {} // https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2
            }
        }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    },
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        }
    },
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img/UI_icons/',

                src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/UI_icons/'
            }]
        }
    },
    // cssmin: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //                 '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //                 '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                /*removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                // https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/44
                //collapseWhitespace: true,
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true*/
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                src: '*.html',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '.htaccess',
                    'empty.html',
                    'preview_export/**',
                    'zip/**'
                ]
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/img',
                src: [
                    '**/*.{ico,txt,png,jpg,gif}',
                ]
            },
            // TODO: figure out what the deal is with the fonts in dist mode...
            {
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                flatten: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles',
                src: [
                    '**/*.woff'
                ]
            },
            {
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/strut.themes',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/strut.themes',
                src: [
                    '**/*.png',
                    '*.css'
                ]
            }]
        }
    },
    bower: {
        all: {
            rjsConfig: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/main.js'
        }
    },
    jasmine : {
        src: ['common/collections/MultiMap.js', 
'framework/ServiceRegistry.js'],
        options: {
          specs : 'jtest/spec/*.js',
          vendors : ['libs/jQuery.js', 'libs/lodash.js', 
'libs/backbone.js'],
          template: require('grunt-template-jasmine-requirejs'),
          templateOptions: {
            requireConfig: {
                    baseUrl: 'app/scripts/',
                    path : {
                       jquery : 'libs/jQuery',
                       lodash : 'libs/lodash'
                    }
            }
          }
        }
    }
});

// grunt.renameTask('regarde', 'watch');

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'open', 
'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'handlebars',
        'livereload-start',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'connect:test',
    'mocha'
]);

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'handlebars',
    'useminPrepare',
    'requirejs',
    'imagemin',
    'htmlmin',
    'concat',
    // 'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy',
    'replace',
    'usemin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    // 'jshint',
    'jasmine',
//        'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```